# Segmentation Fault(core dumped) in nam

Tags: ns2, nam

I have installed ns2 and % sign appears when I type ns on terminal.But when I type nam,the nam window is not opening and segmentation fault(core dumped) error appears.Also when I run "ns filename.tcl" the nam window doesn't open.What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Probable an  installed Ubuntu package :  nam_**.deb. The nam packages for Ubuntu 12.04 ... 16.10 are corrupt. An OK package : https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ns-stop-couldn%27t-execute-nam-permission-denied-while-executing-exec-nam-4175524760/#2

Remove the faulty package : `sudo apt-get remove nam` . Download, and install a new package : `cd Downloads/ && sudo gdebi [package**.deb]`

You can also build `nam` from the updated ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing

```
tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz
cd ns-allinone-2.35/
./install
cd nam-1.15/
sudo make install   ('make install' will copy the executable 'nam' to /usr/local/bin/)
```

Note : The installed nam package.deb (/usr/bin/nam ) must also be removed, when you build a new `nam`.